# ImportError: libc10_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libtorch

I'm now trying to train my own model in a conda environment, using ABCNet with Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA 10.2. Got a complaint: "libc10_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I reinstalled CUDA-10.2 but the problem still remains. For more details, please see the transcripts below.

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 python tools/train_net.py --config-file configs/BAText/Pretrain/attn_R_50.yaml OUTPUT_DIR text_pretraining/attn_R_50 
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "tools/train_net.py", line 40, in from adet.data.dataset_mapper import DatasetMapperWithBasis File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/init.py", 
line 1, in from adet import modeling File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/modeling/init.py", 
line 2, in from .fcos import FCOS File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/modeling/fcos/init.py", 
line 1, in from .fcos import FCOS File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/modeling/fcos/fcos.py", 
line 10, in from adet.layers import DFConv2d, NaiveGroupNorm File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/layers/init.py", 
line 5, in from .bezier_align import BezierAlign File "/home/zzr/AdelaiDet/adet/layers/bezier_align.py", 
line 7, in from adet import _C 
    ImportError: libc10_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That library is not part of CUDA. It is part of libtorch

Comment: @talonmies So how could I fix this? Reinstall the whole torch? Thanks.

Comment: No idea sorry. I am just pointing out why I changed the tags and edited the question and to steer you in the right direction towards finding a solution. You don't have a CUDA problem, you have a libtorch problem

Comment: Still appreciate your help. I think reinstallation may work.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am having same problem. even re-install is not helping.

Comment: For my case, I reinstalled the whole thing including CUDA and pytorch libs and it worked somehow. Don't know what the reason is.  Sorry I couldn't help much.